# Programmatically set the current database or catalog in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

We have a number of databases in our clusters and for certain operations (i.e. creating schemas or other objects), we want to apply the same change across the DBs in a cluster.

Is there a way to "set catalog" to switch among databases?
for example:

set catalog db1;
create schema foo;

set catalog db2;
create schema foo;
...

Of course, I can execute a .sql file containing any statements changing the database in that cluster. I'm looking for an option that allows us to "connect-once" and execute the bulk of the changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the connection to redshift is specific to just 1 database. not possible to switch.

Comment: There is no "USE database" statement, but for querying there is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cross-database-overview.html -- but nothing about DDL or even INSERT/UPDATE operations (into the "other" DB).