# How to switch database in Redshift serverless

Tags: database, switch-statement, amazon-redshift, serverless

I have created redshift serverless cluster and the database name called 'dev' created by default. I have created different databases and each databases have external schema s3_external_schema which is pointing to different s3 bucket.

**dev**

schemas

```
 catalog_history
```

**datbase1**

schemas

```
s3_external_schema
```

**datbase2**

schemas

```
s3_external_schema
```

**datbase3**

schemas

```
s3_external_schema
```

Have created the users and able to provide access to all the databases; However, I am getting an error "SQL Error [3F000]: ERROR: Schema "s3_external_schema " does not exist when I am trying to provide schema access to the users in database1.

GRANT ALL
ON SCHEMA s3_external_schema
TO
"user1";

By default my grant statement executing it under 'dev' database which doesn't have s3_external schema. How do I switch the db from dev to 'database1' so that I can provide schema access to respective users?

I tried to switch the database expecting current_database() should point to different one but didn't work as expected.

Comment: You can only switch the database during connection, but not with a SQL statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252023/programmatically-set-the-current-database-or-catalog-in-redshift

Answer (score 0):

I dont know my answer is correct or not.
In my case, I just use Query Editor V2a and switch by choosing database like below
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).